# Strong community support for a bad answer; why?

Tags: discussion

I recently joined English Language & Usage because I enjoy the topic of English language and have (so far) had positive experiences at other Stack Exchange websites. I also wanted to comment on what I thought was an interesting question:

[Gender-neutral alternative to "craftsmanship"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205282/gender-neutral-alternative-to-craftsmanship)

This title summarises the question well. The answer, I would think, could either dispute the premise of the question or answer it. In other words, this should not have been a controversial question: you can answer the question by either giving examples of words that *are* gender-neutral or provide reasoning for why "crafstmanship" *is* gender neutral. Simple!

The [accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/205347/96294) does a good job of answering the question by providing non gender-specific synonyms, but the [most highly voted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/205284/96294), which received quite an extraordinary number of votes and was posted by a seemingly reputable member of this community, didn't answer the question and didn't provide (sound) reasons for why the premise was false:

> Yes, there is: realizing that "craftsmanship" is gender-neutral.
>   People who think it is not should take it up with themselves, not the
>   word.
>
> If I see discrimination where there is none, the root of the problem
>   is myself and not the language. It is also a textbook example of an
>   etymological fallacy.
>
> Craftsmanship implies "man" about as much as woman does.

I interpreted these 3 paragraphs as follows:

1. The OP is irrational and should seek introspection, as he/she is lashing out at a word.
2. The question contains a logical fallacy, and the questioner is the root cause of a *perceived* problem.
3. The premise of the question is incorrect.

The first paragraph doesn't add any value, and shouldn't really be part of an answer. If the answerer was intending to make the argument that the word *craftsmanship* is in fact gender-neutral, he or she didn't make the reasons for this clear, and therefore the paragraph really only serves to deride the questioner.

The second paragraph begins with a dubious segway into the topic of discrimination and then makes the assertion that the question contains a fallacy, neither of which address the question.

The last paragraph seems to be a conclusion based on the "arguments" provided.

This is clearly a poor answer. The answer only addresses the question in so far as it claims the question is invalid, but fails even in that regard because it provides no meaningful explanation as to why.

This website is for [linguists, etymologists, and serious enthusiasts](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so while I can understand that poor answers come up once in a while (stack overflow is by no means immune to this), I was disappointed to see such strong support for this answer, which was provided by a user with a very high rating who is clearly a significant member of this community.

The community clearly *accepts* this as the correct answer.

Does this answer reflect the views of the community, or did the question just happen to [touch a nerve](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C_PG4n-gyIE/UG23uTYLgaI/AAAAAAAABQY/mfFUp9BxGK8/s1600/tangled-disney-movie-1400x1050.jpg) for some members?

Am I incorrect in my interpretations of the answer and my view that it fails to address the question?

Comment: You are [very new to ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/96294/quant), having so far contributed nothing but complaints. However, we will give you the benefit of the doubt and hope that you will grow to become a participant not just a spectator or kibitzer. In contrast,  [the individual you are complaining about](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/300/regdwigнt) has contributed quite literally infinitely more than you have.  Were those positions reversed, I rather doubt we would be having this conversation. There’s a good reason why it’s called ***reputation*** you know.

Comment: @tchrist Is the point that I'm not supposed to post here about his answer? I don't get it.

Comment: The point is that your very first posting was one complaining about one of the longest serving, most productive and hardest working, and most respected members of our entire community.  You could have made a better entrance, and it probably would have been better if you had, because that way you would have had some reputation to stand on of your own.  Right now, you don’t.  This too shall pass.   I hope.

Comment: @tchrist I don't think we disagree about any of the facts; I just got here and had a whinge, fine. You're a **reputable** member; do _you_ think it was a good answer?

Comment: Do I think it was a “good” answer?  I think it was a good-enough answer. Sure, he could have rambled on like I did defending him, but that’s my style, not his. He made his point and got out. Don’t make too big a deal of it: it isn’t worth all this analysis and time. There are a lot more things to worry about than a multicollider anomaly.

Comment: @tchrist, well we both seem to agree he didn't qualify his point, and we _know_ that he didn't answer the question, so disregarding our opinions on the subject, I still don't see how this is a stellar answer.

Comment: There are no stellar answers, [only stellar questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/stellar-question?userid=300). :)

Comment: You've written a balanced fair and objective first meta post. I hope you stick around, EL&U should be encouraging native speakers such as yourself to contribute. We all had to start from somewhere.

Comment: @tchrist I don't believe that quant has posted only "complaints", I think they are fair observations which he posted beneath the top scoring answer. The poster didn't reply, which I can sympathise with, but likewise it's understandable why quant is confused. He didn't read the interminable train of comments that contributed (IMO) to the frenzied attention that the " elegant alternative to *sportspersonship*" question had attracted.

Comment: Quant: not all questions have the answer they are looking for. "What is the word for X?" may have no word. And the highest voted question is pointing that out. So it is not a 'bad' answer, it's giving a non-answer because it thinks there is no answer is it is telling that. It may be right, it may be wrong, but saying there is no answer _must_ be a possibility.

Comment: @Mitch I think we're all in agreement on that, my point was that this is not what the answer did.

Comment: I see only strong community support for a good answer on a bad question ;)

Comment: @tchrist: Doesn't the entire Stack Exchange network, and EL&U in particular, have a policy of judging a post on its own merits, rather than on the merits of the person who posted it? If you want to say that *this* **question** is too much complaint for too little content, that's fine. But your comments that the *poster* is too new and too complaining, and that it's somehow not his place to criticize an established *user* on this site is unjustified and condescending. Read quant's question again. He is criticizing the *quality* of the **answer**. He has no quarrel with the answerer.

Comment: I happened to think it was not a very good answer. However, the question of gender-neutral language is not my main field of interest in linguistics. It is a personal interest in the political sociological field, but that is for another site. As I was not prepared give any answer to the question itself, and as a newish member here, I did not feel it appropriate to comment on any answer. I doubt if I will ever feel it appropriate to question the motives of members of the community who happen to upvote a response that is not to my liking.

Comment: I'm pretty flabbergasted that this answer is being defended so vigorously, given that it does NOT provide either: 1. An answer to the question as asked or 2. any sort of evidence to support the claim that the question is unnecessary.  
This is the fundamental flaw with Stackexchange, that someone's reputation grants them license to ignore the rules.
Moreso, I'm flabbergasted that a perfectly legitimate question about this dubious answer is being defended with logical fallacies like "you complain too much" and "That poster has been here a long time" as if these somehow had any relevance.

Comment: It's much harder to be careful and considerate of others than it is to just tell others they are wrong when trying to find a less hurtful way of doing things. No one wants to acknowledge that (intentionally or not) the words they say can be hurtful. And look, here's someone saying they don't have to change, they don't have to choose their words with care, and it's the person  who is mislabeled's fault for being offended.

Comment: @barbecue Consider answering the question, “What is the gender-neutral version of *human*?”  Sometimes the right answer is that the question is wrong. This is one of those times.\

Comment: @tchrist: I agree that this is one of those times.  However, an answer saying “your assumptions are wrong!” is doubly obliged to *back up its claims*, or at the very least, explain them carefully.  The answer in question simply states its claim as though it were obvious and indisputable.  So I (reasonably reputable, if not so active recently) would agree with quant that, while right, it leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @tchrist Your last comment misrepresents the question though. Even if "craftsmanship" *is* a gender-neutral word, the poster asked for an alternative. Unlike your example with "human", there *are* gender-neutral alternatives to it—["artisanship" is listed in the oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/artisanship) with [the same exact definition as "craftsmanship"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/craftsmanship). So the question is not "wrong", wrong is the assumption by seemingly everyone that whoever posted the question had an agenda.

Comment: Actually, you could easily say that Homo Sapiens is a gender-neutral alternative to Human.

Comment: There is a well know asynchronicity with questions that hit the super collider. Drive by voters with just the rep from the association bonus can only vote up not down. So even if it was viewed by as many people that rolled their eyes at it as agreed with it the votes would only go one way.

Comment: @aslum hardly, _homo_ [means _man_](http://latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/homo).

Comment: Man as in human as in Earthling (assuming Latin root) OR Same (assuming Greek root). Draw your own conclusions (I know you already have.)

Comment: "The answer <...> could <...> dispute the premise of the question" - that's exactly what it did.

Comment: **I'm pretty flabbergasted that this answer is being defended so vigorously, given that it does NOT provide either: 1. An answer to the question as asked...**  Indeed. It's That Simple.

Comment: "Sometimes the right answer is that the question is wrong. This is one of those times."  What a load of utter stinking silly nonsense.  A non-sexed version of "craftsmanship" could not be a more obvious, clear, good, question in the "non-sexed language" field.  Note that indeed a number of sensible solutions were discussed. Any number of eg web sites that USE NON-SEXED VERSIONS of this word were brought up. You cannot seriously be suggesting the same question featuring say "chairman" would be "not a question".  Give me a break.

Comment: @tchrist No, it's not one of those times. Here's the definition of the word "Craftsman" from the OED. 
craftsman, n.
Pronunciation:  /ˈkrɑːftsmən/ /-æ-/
Forms:  ME–15 craftes, craftis man, (ME craftus, craftise man, ME craftiesman), ME–15 craftisman, craftysman, craftesman, 15–16 craftes-, crafts-man, 15– craftsman.... (Show More)
Etymology:  Originally two words in syntactical relation: compare tradesman.
 1. A man who practises a handicraft; an artificer, artisan.

Comment: The OED's etymology for Human is completely different. The truth is, claiming that the words "craftsman" and "human" are equally gender neutral is demonstrably factually incorrect.

Human: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89262 
Craftsman: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/43712

Comment: Etymology has little to no weight nowadays. @barbecue

Comment: OP of original question here.  Quite surprised to find my question has generated so much discussion of which I've been unaware.

If anyone is curious, my question had no ulterior motives.  I personally think that "craftsman" connotes gender in the same way that "policeman" and "sportsman" do.  I try to avoid gendered terms in my own language, and was trying to find a way to do that in this case.  I was not trying to criticise anyone else.

I found the highly up-voted answer and surrounding comments very hostile, and have avoided using the English Stack Overflow since.

Comment: @Cai same here. Without putting too fine a point on it, the top voted answer was a rant. To see it rank so highly (and be made by such a respected member) really made me lose interest in this community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There have been many responses to the question and I think it makes the most sense for me to try to collate them somehow, rather than picking a single answer. I'm reluctant to hijack my own question like this but unless someone comes up with an objective review I don't think it makes sense for me to accept the other answers.

I had initially chosen [tchrist's answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5306/96294) because it did address my question, but it also contained some the same emotional digressions that prompted me to write this post in the first place. Given the strong response to my post I think this page deserves a more complete answer.

Let's start with (a summary of) the original question:

> What is a gender-neutral alternative to *craftsmanship*?

There are at least 2 ways to read this question:

1. "What is a gender-neutral alternative to craftsmanship?"
2. "Saying *craftsmanship* is sexist, what's a non-sexist word?"

Obviously these are extremes; the first is a cold literal reading and the second is a disproportionate response that could not have been made by an objective individual. There is a spectrum between these two interpretations and as human beings it seems we are unable to separate emotional inference from the words we see on a page. Those who read the words closer to 2) might have further inferred *intention* and interpreted this question as something along the lines of:

> I wish to impose upon you a non-sexist version of *craftsmanship*. What word should I use?

When I read the question like this, it makes much more sense why it received the kind of response it did. With this paraphrase of the original question in mind, let's look at the winning answer again:

> ...[realize] that "craftsmanship" is gender-neutral.
>   People who think it is not should take it up with themselves, not the
>   word.
>
> If I see discrimination where there is none, the root of the problem
>   is myself and not the language. It is also a textbook example of an
>   etymological fallacy.
>
> Craftsmanship implies "man" about as much as woman does.

I was initially baffled by this response, but if we read it in the context of my paraphrased question, it *makes sense*.

If the original question was an unnecessary attack on *our* right to use our language freely, I too might have been inclined to respond like this!

If you are still not convinced, here is an excerpt from tchrist's response to my question:

> All this over-sensitivity about non-existent issues smacks of
>   political correctness gone mad, like people are just looking for
>   something to complain about

This is another example of a response that is not really a response to the question (mine nor the original question), but a response to a perceived attack or infringement of rights.

I do not think I've taken this line out of context, as there is no mention in that post of this over-sensitivity being only *perceived* or *inferred*. He seems to be quite adamantly claiming that such over-sensitivity is *real* and that the questioner was erroneously propagating such an idea.

If we put down our argument sticks for a minute and accept, for better or worse, that the original question was in fact viewed through a *lens* from which the literal meaning of the question is skewed, then these responses begin to make sense. The ensuing arguments are then simply the result of a disconnect in perception; one side was defending itself against an attack on liberty, and the other against an attack of bigotry.

Both of these are noble goals which are not all mutually exclusive. Had this difference in perception been communicated there would likely never have *been* a conflict, or at least a far milder one. I think we have to view the discussion in this light if we genuinely want to understand and learn from the reactions to the original question.

The strong community support is likely to have been in a similar vein. As [tchrist pointed out](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5306/96294), the question hit the "network-wide superconducting multicollider" and the answer might therefore have benefited from upvotes as new members with only the [association bonus](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/what-is-the-association-bonus) didn't have enough reputation to downvote the answer.

Having read through the comments and answers here and on the original question, I think that this is at least a rough description of what happened. I can't of course know what everyone involved *really* thought. At the end of the day, we're emotional creatures, and my argument that the answer was objectively a poor one was perhaps missing the point as much as those who upvoted the answer in the first place!

This has been a wonderful learning experience for me. I think I could spend years learning about what happened here, how it would have gone differently among different cultures, and what analogues of this scenario manifest in the various conflicts we engage in on a daily basis.

If I were Cai (the poster of the [original question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205282/gender-neutral-alternative-to-craftsmanship)), and knowing what I have learnt over the last few days, I would have phrased the question in the following way:

> Without discussing whether or not *craftsmanship* is a gender-specific term, and disregarding any
>   etymological arguments one way or the other, could you suggest a synonym that is less likely to be inferred as having a gender-specific connotation?

I believe that such a phrasing of the question would have had a greater chance of garnering the desired responses, and might have pre-emptively disarmed some of the commentary we have seen.

Comment: Your perspective is refreshingly balanced. Thanks for not contributing to the take-sides mentality.

Comment: Excellent analysis. Forgive the effusiveness, but I think it's great to have your voice here.

Comment: Wow, you're actually taking time out to understand another person's mindset. Holy crap, we have the beginnings of understanding each other.

Comment: "a disproportionate response that could not have been made by an objective individual." The only reason to *have* the question is a belief that the word is, as they say, "problematic". To ask, in a public space, "what is a gender neutral alternative to X?" is inherently to charge that one thinks X is not gender neutral, contra the margarine analogy. Which, in turn, is inherently a moral value claim that X needs to be changed for the benefit of society - because you wouldn't want to *not* be "gender neutral", *right*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think that's one valid interpretation, yes. Although I'm not sure I agree that you wouldn't want a word to not be gender neutral. There's nothing inherently wrong with gendered words, at least not that I'm aware of. Maybe I've missed your point?

Comment: The rhetoric "because you wouldn't want to *not* X, *right?*" is intended to connote a particular sort of political pressure. My claim is that such pressure was commonly exerted on the Internet in 2014 and is still an important phenomenon today. I happen to value freedom of speech and the English language both very highly, and as such I am extremely averse to what I perceive as attempts to impose artificial changes to the latter.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think one of the challenges of creating constructive dialog in a community like this (or any community, really) is to be able to compartmentalise and remain focused. I personally didn't take any implied political pressure from the question, but if anyone felt it was implied I think the correct response would have been to ignore it in the answer and correct the bias in the question.

Comment: ... or at least, addressing the substance of the question and the political agenda separately.

Comment: My argument is that *the question cannot be asked without bias*. The *point* of asking such a question is to express the bias I describe, and "the bias in the question" comes from its *fundamental premise*. People who don't have that bias, don't have an interest in having questions of that sort answered - because they *necessarily understand* that there *isn't a problem with the word*. No words following this pattern were ever biased, and society as a whole was wrong to try to correct them in the first place - in the early 90s just as in the mid 10s.

Comment: Sorry you've lost me. I don't understand how a question about a word is necessarily biased. If you're trying to say that the original word is gender neutral already, then that's a perfectly valid answer. If someone had asked for a gender neutral word for "king" would your response be different?

Answer (score 37):

The question apparently hit the network-wide superconducting multicollider, which pulls in drive-by voters from all SE sites everywhere. It is therefore possible that most of those votes were not actually from regular members of the active ELU  community.

However, [*all* SE sites’ have postings whose votes totals can seem disproportionately high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198906).  There are some truly mystifying examples of one-liners garnering votes far beyond what one would imagine. [Some of these high-scoring ELU postings “make sense”](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&pagesize=50&q=score%3a95), but many of them do not.

Everybody has their own reasons for voting as they do.  You should not expect this to always “make sense”.  Short, simple postings that are easily digested are always going to draw votes quicker than things that require work to read through;  [it’s just how people are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange). Consider [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/574/) or [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/85248). Does that seem sensible?  Furthermore, joke postings [have always been an issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68060).

Although we can really never know why this one has skyrocketed, I would not be surprised if the votes came from people strongly agreeing with the sentiments  expressed by the poster.  You will notice that it has as many downvotes as the OP-selected answer has.

However, I do think that you are coming down too hard on that answer. It is not a bad answer, and it is not derisive that I can see.

It’s perfectly germane to point out that a word’s origins are irrelevant to its currently understood meaning, and that it is a fallacy to believe they do matter.  They don’t.

As far as I can see, the answer is correct, because *crafts**man**ship* really is no more a gendered term than ***man***ikin is, whatever their origins.  We don’t need a new word for manikins in store windows sporting women’s lingerie, either, and it is a fallacy to think that we somehow ought to do that.  A manikin is just manikin; it is not a man any longer, not even a wee one.

That’s the sort of thing that leads to nonsense like forbidding the use of ***alter***nate  or *be**tw**een* for more than two choices, or avoiding *in**cul**cate* or ***con***notation because they might appear to contain a somewhat rude word-element (well, if French) inside them, or being afraid to use *seminal* for ideas unrelated to procreation.

Nobody expects *un**man**ned* drones to be carrying *wo**men*** in them, either.  A “gay-rights” campaign against the Canadian practice of buying ***homo*** milk would be similarly misguided, just as one driven by a bunch of troglodytes to rename the genus of ***Homo*** sapiens to something more **all**-inclusive of women like ***Pan*** sapiens would be.

Those all sound silly.  Or at least, I sure hope they do.

All this over-sensitivity about non-existent issues smacks of political correctness gone mad, like people are just looking for something to complain about. It’s just like how insisting on the ungainly monster-construct *“he/she”* instead of the more natural *they* is bound to annoy people.  Quite a lot of people are fed up with all that bother, you see, and for a very simple reason: because **being told how you can or cannot talk *really* rubs people the wrong way!**

This is especially galling when it’s making stuff out of thin air as appears to be the case here, but even if it weren’t, it would still vex.

Eventually, there’s going to be push-back in response to these teapot tempests about in-words and out-words. It rankles. Perhaps that’s  why so many voted that answer up, because they are tired of being rankled by such silly-in-their-eyes hassles, and they see that posting as speaking to that matter.

Maybe.

In the final analysis, we cannot know why that answer got the votes it got, but it does not matter that we cannot know why.  These things always happen, and there is no reason to get upset over them.  All SE sites have similar issues — or non-issues, as the case may be.

Comment: *It is not a bad answer, and it is not derisive that I can see.* - maybe derisive was a poor choice of wording. I meant that the answer was not productive and was clearly the product of an emotional response. The points you make are all valid, but they are yours, not his. Don't you think a good answer would have backed up some of these claims? I take your point about drive-by voting.

Comment: There are [about 3,590 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22her+craftsmanship%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books for *her craftsmanship*. The ratio between that and ***his** craftsmanship* is around 1:8, which is much the same as the ratio between *her skill* and *his skill*. I upvoted Reg's answer without the benefit of that supporting information, *because I agreed with what it said*. I certainly don't accept that I erroneously endorsed a "bad" answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Based on what you wrote I'd say you have probably misunderstood the original question, as well as my post here.

Comment: @quant I too agree with the answer being questioned and I'd give it my upvote. I believe *"craftsmanship" is gender-neutral*. Take **mankind** for example.

Comment: Drive-by voter here, I arrived at that question via the Hot Network Questions tab.

Comment: Another driver-by. The sentence "All this over-sensitivity about non-existent issues smacks of political correctness gone mad" makes me question whether the highly voted answer *and* the original question are being upvoted based on reasons entirely external to the issue at hand. Since when do SE communities judge the quality of any question or answer based on the perceived political agenda of the poster?

Comment: @quant I object to the "not productive and clearly the product of an emotional response" part. I am not one bit invested in this, one way or the other, emotionally or otherwise. I can argue the exact opposite viewpoint with the same gusto and dedication. Or rather, the same lack of dedication. The question asked for a word that meant 'craftsmanship' without being gender-specific, and I posted one such word. Just like everyone else did. The rest is just voting, over which I have no influence, and endless discussions in comments, in which I neither had nor desired a say.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I'm right behind you on this one, obviously. But would you not accept that your answer *would* have been better if it had included some kind of "objective support" for the position? Something like my "relative prevalence in Google Books" point as made above, tchrist's telling references to morphemes in *manikin, unmanned, between, inculcate*, or whatever.

Comment: @Fumble I did reference *woman* for just that reason — even though I thought it superfluous. Same goes for that Wikipedia link I added. The thing is, I expected "a gender-neutral term for *craftsmanship* is *craftsmanship*" to be a boring truism, the likes of "a term for *craftsmanship* with 13 letters is *craftsmanship*". I went out of my way not to attack anyone in particular ("people"), and indeed to explicitly include myself in the group of those being attacked ("I"). Alas. Hindsight is 20/20, and when people want to misinterpret a post in the most unfavorable manner, they *will*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: As ever, you have a veritable armoury of additional justifications to call upon when pressed! :) Personally, if I were in your position I think I'd probably stick to my guns and refuse to pander to prejudice by fiddling with the text of a perfectly valid answer to a relatively tiresome question. But then again, I'm not a mod. And given the current furore over another mod-related issue, it does rather look as if the mod-baiting season has just opened. Maybe *something* needs to be done to lower the temperature.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I obviously don't know what you were thinking when you wrote the answer, if it were in the original post I'd adjust it. What I don't understand is how you could have answered the question in such a way _without_ having been just a tad annoyed at the question. I don't think that's an unfair assessment. Obviously this whole thread has gotten a bit out of proportion. But am I wrong? Did you not read into it a bit too far and get just a little annoyed to see *yet another* PC fanatic when you read the question? Be honest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I fail to see what your [Google Books results](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/strong-community-support-for-a-bad-answer-why#comment20701_5306) prove. Of course **her craftsmanship** will produce those types of figures, there isn't any viable alternative, yet. I'm sure that Google Books will produce interesting results for *women doctors*; *doctoress*; *doctoresses*, and *female doctors* compared to, say, *male doctors* and *men doctors*. (cont'd.)

Comment: Nowadays the term, *doctor* is recognized as being neutral. There are no overtones of it being specifically a male profession, as it once was in the past. In Italy, however, it is still convention to call a "female doctor", *dottoressa*, but it is void of discrimination and sexism because in Italian nouns have genders. It is a grammatical rule, it has nothing to do with sexism. But English is different. It doesn't have that constriction. There is no grammatical rule which says a noun HAS to be either female of male.  (cont'd.)

Comment: And I'd like to add that I don't find *craftsmanship* neither offensive nor sexist, but that's me. BUT I don't find the request for a gender neutral equivalent to be absurd, or worthy of derision, as proven by the shameful number of downvotes on the OP's questions, and the equally shameful number of upvotes for that answer. Furthermore, allow me to point out yet another blindingly obvious question which nobody has addressed. The proportion/ratio of male voters vs, female voters. What is it? And how many women would agree with the highest up-voted answer, given the opportunity?

Comment: And, finally, whether anybody likes it or not, the *connotations* of craftsmanship is male. A man who is skilled at his craft is a *craftsman*; not a *craftsperson*, a *craftsbeing*, or a *craftsapiens*. From the term *craftsman* we obtain the noun, *craftsmanship*. Ha! I've coined a new word, *craftsapienship*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Include yourself in those being attacked? Please. That is utterly disingenuous. Your "explicit self-inclusion" was of the form "If I am so stupid as to believe X, I should be questioning my own intelligence." That is not a dispassionate way to express your view. You clearly *don't* consider yourself stupid enough to believe X. Let me try a less incendiary formation: "If I have a billion dollars, I'm rich." Let me ask you: am I explicitly including myself among the wealthy there when I say "I"?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: The reason I specifically compared ***him/her*** and ***craftsmanship/skill*** is because if a significant number of people think ***craftsmanship*** has unwanted strong male gender associations, I'd expect the ratio for ***her skill*** to differ from ***her craftsmanship***. I believe Italian still has gender built in to the language, so your perspective may not reflect that of the typical modern Anglophone (which I count myself as).

Comment: @FumbleFingers [**her craft**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22her+craftsmanship%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22her+craft%22) receives 58,400 results, a much higher number of hits than *her craftsmanship*. What does this prove? That the word, *craft*, is non-sexist? That authors feel awkward using *craftsmanship* in connection with women? Does this figure actually *prove* or demonstrate anything?

Comment: [**her art**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22her+craftsmanship%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22her+art%22) has 421,000 results. The expression, [**his art**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22her+craftsmanship%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22his+art%22), gets 2,610,000 hits. What do these figures prove? To me they prove that there are more men artists than women, that there are more *famous* men artists than women, that historically, the "fine arts" was a male dominated profession and that is still true today.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I'm not a statistician, but my starting point is that ***skill*** and ***craftsmanship*** have similar meanings, and only the latter might be considered "gender-biased". But the ratio of ***his*** to ***her*** is very close for both words - meaning writers are clearly *not* avoiding ***her craftsmanship***. I further assume that the 16 people who upvoted my first comment can understand this relatively simple deduction. At 6:1 the ratio between ***his/her art*** is somewhat different - probably because ***art*** is on average used differently to ***skill*** and ***craftsmanship***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK. Call me dumb, the "simple deduction" (logical inference) that you claim is clear, I don't get. So what about the expression *her craft* and the 58,400 instances? Does this confirm your position?

Comment: It seems to me that, even if it's true that _craftsman_ has a non-gender-specific origin, it is a gendered word __now__. Language use and meaning changes, and if today we perceive it as implying male artisans rather than female ones, then it does. So the search for a gender-neutral alternative is perfectly valid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Perhaps, I can explain myself better. Seeing as the term *craftsmanship* exists, and has existed for hundreds of years, and as of today there is no well-established alternative (excluding artisan perhaps), the fact that writers are not deliberately avoiding the term, seems to me irrelevant. What is being discussed today is whether an OP has grounds for asking if there's an *obviously* non-gendered term equivalent. Now, if someone replies there is none, that craftsmanship is gender neutral. That is an answer, but it also seems to me that it belittles the OP's request.

Comment: (cont'd.) In that it does not explain *why*, it states it as a fact, which you could argue it is. But I thought EL&U encouraged well-researched answers, answers that are complete and "self-contained". One link to "Etymological fallacy" can be misconstrued as being insulting towards the OP

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I think we're going round in circles. You start from the position that *craftsmanship* [still] implies gender, which Reg & I dispute. Those are conflicting *opinions*. But you've consistently ignored the fact that ***skill*** is a reasonably close synonym that has no gender implications, which means it *is* meaningful to compare gender-specific usages for *craftsmanship/skill*. That gives us statistical information about actual usage, which is *not* just opinions. There might be flaws in Google Books, or in my reasoning, but as yet you've identified none.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fine. OK.

Comment: Apropos nothing, I'd guess that the reason the *his/her* ratio for *art* being somewhat closer (at 6:1) than those for *skill/craftsmanship* is that historically/sociologically, women are more associated with (creative) art than they are with (technological) skill. The ratio with *his/her **novels*** falls to about 3:1, reflecting the fact that women have been able to overcome the undeniable cultural gender bias more in novel-writing than in areas requiring technical/practical expertise.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The incidence of *his craft* over *her craft* might also be that more ship captains — or if you prefer, ships’  masters — are male. JUST KIDDING!! :)

Answer (score 17):

I agree with [tchrist said](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5306/96603) in regards to why the answer has so many upvotes, especially this bit:

> I would not be surprised if the votes came from people strongly agreeing with the sentiments expressed by the poster.

Which is to say: I believe that it is so highly upvoted because, even though the website itself is for linguists, etymologists, and serious enthusiasts, users have all sorts of backgrounds. This answer is not being upvoted for its merit as an answer, it's being upvoted because it addresses the question asked for its perceived intentions, rather than answering it.

To be more specific: the answer **presumes that the question has a hidden political agenda** (which I also fail to find). And the user answering has a clear problem with the political agenda they perceive, whether or not it is there. And so does the SE community.

In support of this theory, I offer that tchrist's answer makes, more openly, the same assumption:

> All this over-sensitivity about non-existent issues smacks of political correctness gone mad, like people are just looking for something to complain about (…) being told how you can or cannot talk really rubs people the wrong way!
>
> This is especially galling when it’s making stuff out of thin air as appears to be the case here, but even if it weren’t, it would still vex.

Let's roll the clock back a bit. The question at hand is:

> It's straightforward to refer to a "craftsperson" instead of a "craftsman" if one doesn't want to imply a gender. But "craftspersonship", "sportspersonship", and the like seem pretty cumbersome. Is there a more elegant alternative?

I fail to see anything accusatory in it, it's not proposing that this word be banned or that people use a different one and it's not complaining about anything. So I also fail to see why tchrist thinks it "smacks of political correctness gone mad".

I agree entirely with your interpretation of the answer. It *is* derisive in presuming that the person wants a gender-neutral alternative because they feel "craftsmanship" is not gender-neutral on its own. It bashes at people who disagree with his view  ("People who think it is not should take it up with themselves, not the word"). It assumes the poster "sees discrimination where there is none", while none of this is said in the question.

The answer ignores completely the question and addresses what the user who offered it *thinks* the context is. They don't care if the author of the question wanted a word that a feminist character in a book might prefer. They are more interested in lashing out on people who might prefer it for political reasons.

In fact, the answer is ridiculous if you ignore the political agenda it forces on the question. The question doesn't even explicitly state that "craftsmanship" is not gender-neutral, it merely asks for an *alternative* that is. While the use of the word "alternative" might arguably imply this, that is not explicitly written anywhere, and there's no other reason to assume the user who made the question thinks that way.

In a different SE community, such as the cooking one, it might have gone as this:

> **Vegetarian alternative for margarine?**
>
> It's straightforward to use margarine instead of butter if one doesn't want to consume animal products. But for frying, risotto and the like, margarine doesn't add to the flavour. Is there a more flavourful alternative?

And the answer in question would be:

> Yes, there is: realizing that margarine is vegetarian. People who think it is not should take it up with themselves, not the food.
>
> If I see animal products where there is none, the root of the problem is myself and not the food. It is also a textbook example of not reading the label.
>
> Margarine has animal products about as much as lettuce does.

I hope this parody sounds absurd, because this is exactly the level of absurdity I see in the answer posted.

In my opinion, even putting aside the unnecessary aggressiveness, the answer is *still* very poor. It fails to answer the question (as it *doesn't present an alternative*) and doesn't provide any form of justification for the opinion presented. It would be perfectly fine to answer something like:

> According to the Oxford dictionary, the word "[artisanship](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/artisanship)" conveys the same meaning as "[craftsmanship](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/craftsmanship)". Please note, however, that even though "craftsmanship" doesn't appear to be gender-neutral, it in fact is, according to [insert reference here].

The unprovoked aggressiveness of the answer, the unwavering support for it, despite the utter lack of quality (no matter whatever merits the user who posted it has) and the dimension of the reaction to this question lead me to one conclusion: none of this has nothing to do with the question. The question itself is, paraphrasing [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205282/gender-neutral-alternative-to-craftsmanship#comment436576_205282), the windmill that several senile Spanish knights were looking for in this website.

I would also paraphrase the infamous answer by saying that there is *nothing* in the question that justifies such extreme reactions. People who think there is should take it up with themselves, not the question. If one sees political agenda where there is none, the problem is in oneself.

I will, however, do no such paraphrase, as I haven't amassed enough internet-kudos to make this type of outburst acceptable.

Comment: It is entertaining, though also a tad confusing, to see this answer exhibit the very things it is railing against: presumptuousness, absurdity, and failure to answer the question.

Comment: The questions asked were (1) whether the answer reflects the views of the community, which I deferred to the previous accepted answer and expanded upon, (2) whether the interpretations offered were accurate, which I agreed upon, and (3) whether the answer in discussion fails to answer the question, which I stated that it does. This, however, is an answer to a discussion post in Meta, so my subjectivity is, I understand, allowed. That wasn't.

Comment: @RegDwigнt that's a nice opinion... you should back it up with reasons. you're pretty pretentious basically all the time from what i've seen. writing short sentences doesn't preclude pretentiousness.

Comment: Basically, this ballyhoo would have been avoided if the OP had given a different title to his question. *Gender-neutral alternative to "craftsmanship"?* It seems (superficially) that many users did not stop to read the content of the question posted. And, the highest uprated comment, which also happened to be the first posted below the question, said something similar to "man meaning mankind is gender neutral". The EL&U user's comment had already received 50 upvotes before it was deleted.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that comment, which reinforced the tone; pushed and gave users permission to jump on the bandwagon. Please note that an almost identical answer, posted a day later, has to date received 48 upvotes. That answer, infuriated me much more than RegDwight's. At least his was grammatical, eloquent and logical. It didn't make it a *good answer* but it made sense. On the other hand, the "copycat" answer is, in one word, nonsensical. Was I the only one who read that thinking *"What?"*. That answer is unquestionably *bad*.

Comment: @kadu +1 Well put, insightful, clearly done. I thought the margarine example was particularly helpful

Comment: @Mari-LouA It wasn't logical at all. Sorry

Comment: @Araucaria it certainly made more sense, and therefore more logic than the copy-cat answer.

Comment: It seems to me that your margarine example has a flaw in its first line - "It's straightforward to use margarine instead of butter if one doesn't want to consume animal products. " implies "I know margarine is vegetarian". Maybe you meant to say "...use olive oil instead of margarine..." - then the rest of your example would have made sense.

Comment: The margarine analogy doesn't quite fit. Flavor is subjective, where language nuances are objective. So when someone says "I don't like the flavor of margarine; what else can I use?", you can't answer with "you are mistaken about margarine, you should like it." Meaning is objective, so if someone says "If I want to be gender-neutral, what word should I use for *craftsmanship*?", you can reply with "*Craftsmanship* actually bears out a gender-neutral usage, so you can use it." This would be different if the question were "I want to avoid the lexeme *-man-*, what can I use instead?"

Comment: @Daniel The margarine example is not meant to mean that gender neutrality is subjective. I'm not a linguist, therefore not equipped for this discussion. It's meant to indicate that, as well as you can ask for a vegetarian alternative to margarine—**despite it being vegetarian already**—, you can equally ask for a gender-neutral alternative to whatever gender-neutral word you want.

Comment: The OP's request clearly stated that the "problem" with craftsmanship was in the suffix *man*. He gave *craftsperson* and *sportspersonship* as examples of "gender neutrality". As I mentioned previously, it was the OP's title (not the body) which gave users the excuse to vent their anti-PC frustrations.

Comment: "I fail to see anything accusatory in it, it's not proposing that this word be banned or that people use a different one and it's not complaining about anything. So I also fail to see why tchrist thinks it "smacks of political correctness gone mad"." It proposes - incorrectly - that people who *don't* change their language are failing to adopt gender neutrality, and it is *trivially easy* to infer a negative political judgment from that.

Comment: "It's meant to indicate that, as well as you can ask for a vegetarian alternative to margarine—**despite it being vegetarian already**" You can, but it's absurd if you actually know it's vegetarian, and doing so therefore implies that you don't think it is. Gender neutrality is an inherently political topic *because people can and have faced policy repercussions for failing in such neutrality*. Asking for new words to replace those in common use necessarily makes the argument that there is somehow something wrong with those words, and necessarily is an act of advocacy. Language is power.

Comment: "it's absurd if you know it's vegetarian"—"alternative" means "one of two or more available possibilities", people have reasons other than vegetarianism for not wanting margarine, as my answer already stated. // "it is trivially easy to infer a negative political judgment from that"—which doesn't change the fact that the question _can_ be answered objectively, yet commenting on its political subtext seemed more relevant to several participants. Language is political in many ways, this is no excuse to ignore the _language_ question and discuss the _politics_ of it in this SE.

Comment: The biggest absurdity of all, to me, is that after _more than 7 years_ people are still choosing this particular hill to die on. Bizarrely enough, I have a strong suspicion that the same users who were so offended by this question are the same ones who would label the asker a "snowflake".

Answer (score 2):

**Strong community support for a bad answer; why?**

Because it was a bad question; at least poorly worded. And for whatever reason users decided to upvote the *throw this in your face* answer instead of downvoting the question or suggesting an edit. Don't y'all get so pissed when your next question is "Closed because it's unclear what you're asking". This is the result of **moderator failure** and a [community bandwagon event](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206777/word-for-the-sentiment-or-behaviour-of-extra-people-putting-the-boot-in-once-a-m); when the cat's away...

I agree with (TLDR- whoever said it) that the OQ should be deleted or *fixed* as I have also suggested in a comment there: (It is an embarrassment to SE)

> This entire page is garbage until the question is altered to ask whether or not 'craftsmanship' is gender-neutral, or unless changed into a single word request and thereby deleting answers that don't provide one; cleaning up this non-applicable NOISE.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR. I have read the original question and the answer it complained about; that's all. I have certainly not tried to follow all the text on this page. The resultant huhu illustrates a topic we don't really discuss here much -- what to do with false presuppositions. We do about as well as we could expect with linguistic nonsense, I think.

But non-linguistic nonsense, like sexism and racism and political lies, are trickier, since not everyone has the same standards for what's tasty and what's not.

In this case, as pointed out, the question's presupposition was not only false but also offensive to some, and offense was obviously taken. The likelihood of such interactions is one of the reasons we don't discuss these topics. It's easy to distract people.

This answer is not a solution to the problem; nor does it answer the original question, nor this question. But the problem won't go away, and it should not remain unremarked.

Comment: I find this confusing. Some questions that I think need answering before I can understand what is being said here: What is the presupposition that you think is false, if not a linguistic one? In your last paragraph, what is "This answer" (is it your answer, or the one to the original post?), and what is "this question"? When you say "The problem"; what problem? And with "it should not remain unremarked", what is "it"?

Comment: Downvoting as I don't think this answer makes sense, no attempt was made to clarify, and it has a ranty vibe.

Answer (score -5):

As I already pointed out on the question, the situation is extremely simple:

(1) undeniably, each of the five sentences in the answer at hand, is just a political rant against "non-sexed language".

Note that, and this isn't relevant, I personally am completely opposed to the 'non-sexed-language' movement!!!!!! But the situation couldn't be simpler. **"Given"** the 'non-sexed-language' movement, the question asks a **very specific, technical, clear question** about a particular word.

(2) In answer to the question posed here

(i) Voting on the ELU site, in particular, is often nuts

(ii) In spite of the absurdist facade of "referenced! encyclopaedic!" answers, voting on all network sites is, often, essentially political.

Funnily enough here we have **a couple hundred right-wingers expressing their dislike of the 'non-sexed-language' movement** with a vote -- typically it's more the left-wing that crowd votes en masse here.

Please note (OP) that I already marked the answer in question for deletion, since, it should be deleted.

Obviously, on this site the mods just delete any comments they don't like, so this has all been wiped clear on the QA in question.

---

Regarding the sort of pure nonsense the debate on this questionhas provoked, I need only paste in my comment from above:

> "Sometimes the right answer is that the question is wrong. This is one
>   of those times."

What a load of nonsense.  A non-sexed version of "craftsmanship" could not be a more obvious, clear, good, question in the "non-sexed language" field.  Note that indeed a **number of sensible solutions were discussed**. Any number of eg **web sites that ALREADY USE NON-SEXED VERSIONS of this word** were brought up! You cannot seriously be suggesting the same question featuring say "chairman" would be "not a question".  Give me a break.

---

Here's another example from anotherwise hugely intelligent and astute contributor:

> "because craftsmanship really is no more a gendered term than manikin
>   is"

What?  OF COURSE "manikin", and "history" ("herstory"!) is a word that is considered and alternatives sought, by the 'non-sexed-language' movement.

Again where is this "obvious" line drawn?  Of course obviously "craftsman" would be OK to non-sex but "craftsmanship", not OK to non-sex.  How silly.

As someone very astute pointed out in the comments, (in an entrely separate "political language debate") even "niggardly" is treated with great care in the USA, since, (purely "accidentally") it could cause problems.

Good grief.

Comment: I know for a fact that a user suggested in a comment to  RegDwight that the comments ought to be deleted. Each and every single one. The whole atmosphere on that page was inflammatory, to say the least. The comments *annihilated* without distinction, (pro and con) were those beneath RegDwight's and the OP's posts. I don't think the other posters' trail of comments were affected. That deletion, in my opinion helped to calm down the waters. The day after, visiting that same page, everything seemed to be more quiet. There are new "anti-PC" comments, but NOTHING compared to what it was.

Comment: The whole episode to me, is fascinating from a human behaviourist viewpoint. It has been a real eye opener experience.

Comment: Your comments just there appear to have no meaning, because, all the comments **REGARDING COMMENTS BEING REMOVED**, HAVE BEEN REMOVED. That's one way to win a debate!

Comment: So they have. [pause] I'm speechless.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Me too! I don't know what you've taken from this but to me it represents a really intriguing tendency in people to infer strong connections which then shade the words we read and influence our understanding of them. I can't speak for the commenters, but it appears to me like some had literally read the question as "*I disagree with the usage of **craftsmanship** and wish to infringe upon the literary freedoms of those who use it: Discuss.*". It's fascinating, I only wish I could know when I fall victim to this! I'm sure we all do it in different facets of life...

Comment: @quant, but that's exactly it.  The discussion is perpetuating the notion of "craftsmanship is wrong because of gender bias, I'd like to impose a new politically correct term on the world".  It seems to me like politically correct overreach.

Comment: @DoctorJones That argument has been addressed ad nauseum.

Comment: seriously....

history?

Is this going to turn into a clbuttic scenario, where we just censor the male gender completely?